# VBA Excel macro to add rows whenever an ID has no record for that day

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "pessoas" worksheet with a table, which contains a table that links ID's with names.

I have a data "outquery" worksheet with a table that contains all the data in these columns:

| ID | Name (formula) | Date | Entry time | Exit time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Marco Polo | 07/02/2024 | 08:42:00.000 | 15:21:00.000 |

In that same data worksheet I have a small table which contains all the weekdays for that month ("DiasTrabalho").

What I want is a macro that adds rows between existing records whenever an ID has no record for each date. As it stands, I only have data created by entries and exits, if that ID does not record an entry, no data is generated.

Any help is appreciated!

I have made the following code but it does not work, it replaces a few of the top rows of the data table with blank spaces, and creates a new column as well. [Error Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hINJw.png)

```
Sub AddMissingLines()
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim idRange As Range
    Dim dateRange As Range
    Dim cellId As Range
    Dim cellDate As Range
    Dim checkRecord As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Set dataRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("outquery").DataBodyRange
    Set idRange = Worksheets("Pessoas").ListObjects("pessoas").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    Set dateRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DiasTrabalho").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    For Each cellId In idRange
        For Each cellDate In dateRange
            Set checkRecord = dataRange.Find(What:=cellId & cellDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If checkRecord Is Nothing Then
                Set newRow = dataRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                If newRow Is Nothing Then
                    Set newRow = ws.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If
                newRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = cellId.Value
                newRow.Cells(1, 2).Value = cellDate.Value
            End If
        Next cellDate
    Next cellId
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) What's the vlaue of `Entry time` and `Exit time`  for the inserted rows?

Comment: Some screenshots would be useful here.

Comment: I edited the post! The format for those columns has been added.

Comment: It's helpful if you show the contents of `outquery`, `pessoas` and `DiasTrabalho`. Please remember to replace it with dummy data to  prevent data leakage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach to try

```
Sub AddMissingLines()
    Dim dict As Object, r As Long, arrOut, loOut As ListObject, ws As Worksheet, k
    Dim id, dt, arrIds, arrDates
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set loOut = ws.ListObjects("outquery")
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    'get existing table data as 2D arrays
    arrIds = Worksheets("Pessoas").ListObjects("pessoas").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
    arrDates = ws.ListObjects("DiasTrabalho").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
    arrOut = loOut.DataBodyRange.Value
    
    'collect all unique combinations of id and date from the existing "outquery" rows
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrOut, 1)
        dict(GetKey(arrOut(r, 1), arrOut(r, 3))) = True
    Next r
    
    'now check for rows to be added
    For Each id In arrIds
        For Each dt In arrDates
            k = GetKey(id, dt) 'create key
            If Not dict.Exists(k) Then        'new id+date combination?
                With loOut.ListRows.Add.Range 'add a new ListRow and add values to it
                    .Cells(1).Value = id
                    .Cells(2).Value = dt
                End With
                dict.Add k, True
            End If
        Next dt
    Next id
    
End Sub

'create a composite key from an id and a date
Function GetKey(id, dt)
    GetKey = id & ":" & Format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Function
```

Assuming you're on Windows and have access to `scripting.dictionary`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, your execution was very readable!